# PyTorch Transformer Encoder masking sequence values

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer-model

It was my understanding that in the PyTorch `TransformerEncoder` I can pass a mask which would then stop certain features being attended to. By doing so, the model learns to "fill in the gaps" and becomes more resilient to noise and overfitting.

In the documentation for `TransformerEncoder` which I'm using, it is described as a [`mask`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.TransformerEncoder.html) without any details. The other class I use [TransformerEncoderLayer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.TransformerEncoderLayer.html) also doesn't describe it in detail, only the page about [torch.nn.Transformer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Transformer.html) actually goes into some detail.

If I pass a mask which is `[B, S]` where `B` is batch, and `S` is the sequence, I'd be masking *which* part of the sequence to mask.

Alas, trying that ends in an error which says that the mask needs to be `[S,S]` which I don't get why. Going through the internet, this doesn't seem to be asked much, and only this [question on cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/598239/how-is-padding-masking-considered-in-the-attention-head-of-a-transformer) seems to get into it, but without the information I needed.

Aside from using the `padding` mask (which I'd normally use to avoid attending to padded or null values of my Sequence) how can I realistically pass a mask which will tell the model to ignore certain parts of the input sequence (per Batch or per Sequence)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your problem, I guess because of my bad English. Sorry for that.

But I think you are getting src_mask shape error. The problem may be that Transformer receives data as [ S, B ] by default. You can swap the array and batch by using the "permute" function while sending the data to the model. Or you can set the "batch_first" parameter on the Transformer to True.

The problem could be as follows. In Source, you may also want to show the parts that you do not want the model to learn. For this, you need to use the "src_key_padding_mask" assignment in TransformerEncoder.

Transformer Encoder forward method:

```
def forward(self, src: Tensor, mask: Optional[Tensor] = None, src_key_padding_mask: Optional[Tensor] = None) -> Tensor:
```

I can be more helpful when explaining the situation you are talking about with a short piece of code.

Comment: In the future it would be better to ask for clarification in the comments of the question, and only try to answer when the question is clear enough.